# How can i obtain code signing certificate for iOS mobile config profiles

Tags: ios, code-signing, mdm

I am creating iOS mobile config profile and i am pushing the mobile config profile via MDM. In my case i am not using SCEP server for profile management. Simply i create mobile config profile using "iPhone configuration utility" and use the same for mobile settings.

I have created self signed code signing certificate. Using my self signed code sign certificate i signed mobile config profiles as mentioned [here](http://www.steveneppler.com/blog/2011/02/09/signing-ios-mobileconfig-files-with-your-certificate). But for this i have to include my root certificate along with profile.

I want to obtain code signing certificate from a trusted vendor. What kind of code signing certificate i want to purchase. If i purchase Apple code signing certificate, will this help to sign mobile config profiles. [Refer](http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/support.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Several notes:

> In my case i am not using SCEP server for profile management.

SCEP server isn't used for profile management. It's used for identity management. You use either SCEP server or PKCS12 at whenever your need authenticate a device (as example for WiFi, VPN auth or for MDM bootstraping explained here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html)

> I want to obtain code signing certificate from a trusted vendor. What
>   kind of code signing certificate i want to purchase. If i purchase
>   Apple code signing certificate, will this help to sign mobile config
>   profiles.

As I remember you need any SSL certificate. Quite often you both protect communication with your MDM server using it and sign all profiles using it. So, there are no additional requirements for it (on top of usual requirements for SSL certificate).

Surely, you need to check whether certificate of authority which issues this certificate is preinstalled on iOS devices.

Take a look here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012